# Laravel + Vercel Postgress error (ERROR: Endpoint ID is not specified.)

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, vercel

I'm building a private application based on Laravel 10.x now deployed also on Vercel using headless php and the Vercel postgress database.

I'm having issues with the DB connection.

[Database Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Lzr.png)

This error happens after a simple query on DB:

[Database query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHesP.png)

(I've used this endpoint as an example, the clear cache call is not important).

I've already inserted the DB parameters inside the "Environtment Variables" on Vercel and configured also inside the vercel.json file. But still not working.

[Vercel Env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI6Bp.png)

[vercel.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7hYj.png)

-- Edit --

Error message:

`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] ERROR: Endpoint ID is not specified. Either please upgrade the postgres client library (libpq) for SNI support or pass the endpoint ID (first part of the domain name) as a parameter: '?options=endpoint%3D<endpoint-id>'. See more at https://neon.tech/sni (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select * from "newsletters")`

Code:

vercel.json

```js
{
    "version": 2,
    "functions": {
        "api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0" }
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.php"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "APP_NAME": "XXXXXXXX",
        "APP_ENV": "local",
        "APP_DEBUG": "true",
        "APP_URL": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "DB_CONNECTION": "pgsql",
        "DB_HOST": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com",
        "DB_PORT": "5432",
        "DB_DATABASE": "verceldb",
        "DB_USERNAME": "default",
        "DB_PASSWORD": "XXXXXXXX",
        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp/views",
        "SSR_TEMP_PATH": "/tmp/ssr",
        "NODE_PATH": "node",
        "CI": "false"
    }
}
```

/api/index.php

```php
<?php
// This is the front controller for the API. It routes all requests to the public/index.php file.
require __DIR__ . '/../public/index.php';
```

Comment: Could you please post the error message and the relevant code in plain text in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `endpointID` inside the password field.

Example:

```
{ "DB_PASSWORD": "endpoint=ep-fancy-rice-########;<password>", }
```